# Programatically adding an app to a site O365

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, apps-development

Newbie question.  With CSOM how to I add an app to a site.

More detail:  manually you can select options and then "add an app"  The one in particular I am interested in is the Tasks.  I can build any number of lists - but the Tasks APP has extra functionality that is not part of any of the lists I have been able to create.

For instance the check box to close a task, and the timeline.

Once i have added a tasks app to a site - i can populate its list fine.  But I want to build a one click solution and don't want to ask the the user to "Follow These Steps".

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that what I was trying to do was create a list of type **TasksWithTimelineAndHierarchy**  type 171. I found this out when I was trying to figure out how to filter the list of site lists.  The Tasks App used the 171 list.

I wish there was some sort of instructor lead training I could take.  I am getting sick and tired of reverse engineering SharePoint, and Googling everything (and winding up on stack exchange most of the time).

Once you find the answer - you know how you should have asked the question in the first place.

```
 public static void createTasksWithTimelineAndHierarchy(string listTitle,ClientContext context)
    {
        try
        {

            // Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
            // server running SharePoint. 
            //ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl");

            // The SharePoint web at the URL.
            Web web = context.Web;

            ListCreationInformation creationInfo = new ListCreationInformation();
            creationInfo.Title = listTitle;
            creationInfo.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.TasksWithTimelineAndHierarchy;
            List list = web.Lists.Add(creationInfo);
            list.Description = "Month end close for "+listTitle;
            list.Update();
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
        }

    }
```